# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using a `List` object to contain items from a secondary table that my primary table has a one-to-many relationship with. The `PK` of the primary table serves as the `FK` field on the secondary table.

However, I'm getting this error when the record attempts to save

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ClearinghousePartners'. Cannot insert duplicate 
key in object 'dbo.ClearinghousePartners'. The duplicate key value is (0)
```

**Primary Table Model**

FYI - this table contains a LARGE number of fields so I'm just showing the `List`

```
public partial class AgentTransmission
{ 
    .
    .
    public virtual List<ClearinghousePartners> ClearinghousePartners { get; set; }
}
```

**Secondary Table Model**

```
public partial class ClearinghousePartners
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClearingHouseName { get; set; }
    public string TradingPartnerName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public int AgtTransId { get; set; } //FK field corresponds to 'Id' on AgentTransmission

    public virtual AgentTransmission AgentTransmission { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

When the model posts back to the controller to save the exception is thrown in this area of the code. This is an instance in which the `AgentTransmission` object is completely new and needs to be added to the database. Same goes for each item in the `ClearinhousePartners` collection.

Each are brand new `ClearinghousePartners` items with no values for `Id` and `AgtTransId` fields. I need the `AgentTransmission` object to save first so it's `Id` field can be created and THEN inserted into the `AgtTransId` field in the `ClearinghousePartners` objects.

```
agenttransmission.LastChangeDate = DateTime.Now;
agenttransmission.LastChangeOperator = Security.GetUserName(User);
db.AgentTransmission.Add(agenttransmission);
db.SaveChanges(); //Exception thrown here
```

**View**

```
<fieldset id="ClearinghousePartners">
    <legend>Clearinghouse Partners</legend>
    <center>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Clearinghouse Name</th>
                <th>Trading Partner Name</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>                             
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ClearinghousePartners.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr align="center">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClearinghousePartners[i].Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClearinghousePartners[i].AgtTransId)
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClearinghousePartners[i].ClearingHouseName, new { style = "width: 100px" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClearinghousePartners[i].TradingPartnerName, new { style = "width: 100px" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClearinghousePartners[i].StartDate, new { style = "width: 100px" })</td>                                    
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>                            
    </center>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The duplicate key value is (0)

I'm guessing that your table is not set to automatically populate your primary key value as an `identity` property. The declaration should look something like this:

```
ClearinghousePartners int primary key PK_ClearinghousePartners identity
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a new unused value for `ClearinghousePartners.[PrimaryKey]`, or make this column an auto-generated column (referred to as an Identity column in sql server - What RDBMS Are you usng?)